# I/flutter (10710): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developing a flutter application that depends on API REST calls. The Response from the API is a bit complex. I can see the response from the log when calling my API (e.g : api/products) : But i have this Error:

```
type 'List< dynamic >' is not a subtype of type 'Map< String, dynamic >'
```

I've seen all the questions/answers on the internet without any result. I've tried with a simple RestAPI like : https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts and it works. but it doesn't in my case API Response Example :

Here is my code below

```
import 'dart:convert';

MealJSON mealFromJson(String str) => MealJSON.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String mealToJson(MealJSON data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class MealJSON {
  int code;
  MealboxListing data;

  MealJSON({this.code, this.data});

  MealJSON.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    code = json['code'];
    data = data =
        json['data'] != null ? new MealboxListing.fromJson(json['data']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['code'] = this.code;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class MealboxListing {
  AddOn addOns;
  bool availability;
  double averageRating;
  String cityLive;
  String deliveryDate;
  String description;
  List<String> imageDetails;
  String kitchenDetails;
  String listingId;
  int numberOfMeals;
  String origin;
  String title;
  List<String> preferences;
  List<String> tag;
  List<String> included;

  MealboxListing(
      {this.addOns,
      this.availability,
      this.averageRating,
      this.cityLive,
      this.deliveryDate,
      this.description,
      this.imageDetails,
      this.kitchenDetails,
      this.listingId,
      this.numberOfMeals,
      this.origin,
      this.title,
      this.preferences,
      this.tag,
      this.included});

  MealboxListing.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    // addOns = json['add_ons'] != null ? new AddOn.fromJson(json[addOns]) : null;
    availability = json['available'];
    averageRating = json['average_rating'];
    cityLive = json['city_live'];
    deliveryDate = json['delivery_on'];
    description = json['description'];
    imageDetails = json['img_url'].cast<String>();
    kitchenDetails = json['kitchen'];
    listingId = json['listing_id'];
    numberOfMeals = int.parse(json['no_of_meals']);
    origin = json['origin'];
    title = json['title'];
    preferences = json['preferences'].cast<String>();
    tag = json['tags'].cast<String>();
    included = json['whats_included'].cast<String>();
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.addOns != null) {
      data['add_ons'] = this.addOns.toJson();
    }
    data['available'] = this.availability;
    data['average_rating'] = this.averageRating;
    data['city_live'] = this.cityLive;
    data['delivery_on'] = this.deliveryDate;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['img_url'] = this.imageDetails;
    data['kitchen'] = this.kitchenDetails;
    data['listing_id'] = this.listingId;
    data['no_of_meals'] = this.numberOfMeals;
    data['origin'] = this.origin;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['preferences'] = this.preferences;
    data['tags'] = this.tag;
    data['whats_included'] = this.included;
    return data;
  }
}

class AddOn {
  String name;
  String type;
  int price;

  AddOn({
    this.name,
    this.price,
    this.type,
  });

  AddOn.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    price = int.parse(json['price']);
    type = json['type'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['price'] = this.price;
    data['type'] = this.type;
    return data;
  }
}
```

API call

```
static Future<MealboxListing> getData() async {
    String vendorId = await secureStorage.read(key: "cust_id");
    String token = await secureStorage.read(key: "access_token");
    try {
      var res = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            "...."),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
        },
      );
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var resBody = jsonDecode(res.body);
        print(resBody);
        MealJSON mealJSON = mealFromJson(res.body);
        mealboxListing = mealJSON.data;
        print(mealboxListing.description);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Response:

```
{
I/flutter (10710):   "code": 200,
I/flutter (10710):   "data": [
I/flutter (10710):     {
I/flutter (10710):       "add_ons": {
I/flutter (10710):         "0ff2b6ff-7769-43ac-916d-9211de2e221c": {
I/flutter (10710):           "name": "fdsfsdfsdf",
I/flutter (10710):           "price": 5,
I/flutter (10710):           "type": "extras"
I/flutter (10710):         },
I/flutter (10710):         "84d8825f-4628-4af2-bf21-d4ba00897f3b": {
I/flutter (10710):           "name": "fdsfdsf",
I/flutter (10710):           "price": 5,
I/flutter (10710):           "type": "drinks"
I/flutter (10710):         },
I/flutter (10710):         "a2f670dd-7c81-4f2e-8a73-ebd0afcc2758": {
I/flutter (10710):           "name": "ffdfdfd",
I/flutter (10710):           "price": 5,
I/flutter (10710):           "type": "sides"
I/flutter (10710):         }
I/flutter (10710):       },
I/flutter (10710):       "available": true,
I/flutter (10710):       "average_rating": 0.0,
I/flutter (10710):       "city_live": "Fredericton",
I/flutter (10710):       "delivery_on": "Wednesday",
I/flutter (10710):       "description": "fdsfsdfsdf",
I/flutter (10710):       "img_url": [
I/flutter (10710):         "....."
I/flutter (10710):       ],
I/flutter (10710):       "kitchen": "fdsfsdfsdf",
I/flutter (10710):       "listing_id": "6f2202f6-36b4-48d5-b442-b91d790a69a3",
I/flutter (10710):       "no_of_meals": 1,
I/flutter (10710):       "origin": "Canada",
I/flutter (10710):       "preferences": [
I/flutter (10710):         "Vegan"
I/flutter (10710):
```

Stacktrace:

```
I/flutter (10710): type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Comment: Your request is returning a JSON array (possibly of multiple objects), not a single object.

Comment: @msbit how do I access the multiple objects, instead of the single object I am currently getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MealboxListing data;` -> `List<MealboxListing> data;`

`new MealboxListing.fromJson(json['data'])` -> `(json['data'] as Iterable).map((data)=> MealboxListing.fromJson(data)).toList()`

Can you apply this changes and try?

Comment: Can you show me what you want me to change in the snippet of code posted, I am not sure what youre trying to tell me to do/ explain. @Salih Can

Comment: Please correctly format your code. You can do so by pressing Ctrl + k on the code when writing your answer

Comment: After making these changes, this is the exception i am now getting.

type 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, MealboxListing>' is not a subtype of type 'List<MealboxListing>'

Comment: @AneDev I don't think you've added the exception for us to see, but I think you'll need to add `toList()` to the end of what @Salih Can has done here.

Comment: @AneDev From what I saw in your answer, 'data' is not an object but a list. So we have to loop inside the 'data' key and convert it to a list. To be able to loop through it, we must specify it to the compiler with 'as List'.
So for the last error you can try this: ` (json['data'] as Iterable).map((data)=> MealboxListing.fromJson(data)).toList();`

Comment: Also, sorry for the code format, I wrote it from the phone.

Comment: Yes I have been able to add your changes, and it works perfectly. Thank you! @SalihCan